# Flip coins until you get two heads in total, what's the probability that the number of total coins you flipped so far is equal to 4?

Tags: probability

> You flip coins until you get two heads in total, what's the probability that the number of total coins you flipped so far is equal to $4$?

(It's an invalidated problem from a computer olympiad. And I don't know why it's invalidated.)

What I know:

So since you flip until you have a total of $2$ heads, your $n$'th flip should be a head, and in your first $n - 1$ flips you must have $1$ heads.

Then for $n \geq 2$

$\frac{n - 1}{2^{n - 1}} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$

That is $\frac{n-1}{2^n}$

I can see that $\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\frac{n-1}{2^n} = 1$.  But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: What does "flipped so far" mean?  If $X$ denotes the random variable which counts the number of tosses until you have seen two heads, are you asking for $P(X=4)$ or $P(X≥4)$?

Comment: As I said, the question became invalidated. Maybe this is the reason for it. Also, I translated the question, from what I understand it asks the probability of the number of tosses being equal to **4**, so say you have "THTTH" and "THTH", both are valid, but it asks for us to find the probability of having 4 tosses. So we can for example only count "THTH" as a case we want.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  Using the notation I proposed...Do you want $P(X=4)$ or do you want $P(X≥4)$?  Both are valid questions, of course, but it is not clear (either to me or to the user who posted a solution below) which you are asking for.

Comment: I've tried to explain what it is. To me it's neither $P(X = 4)$ or $P(X \geq 4)$. To me, it asks: say "HH, THH, HTH, TTHH, THTH, HTHT, HTTH, TTTHH, ..." is the set of all lists of tosses that end with an "H", and have exactly $1$ H in the first $n - 1$ characters. Let S be the number of elements in this set. This is the set of all cases. But from this set, we only want to know how many lists of tosses have the size of $4$ like "THTH, TTHH, ...". I'm reminding, the question is invalidated. But I do not know the reason.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, not sure you do either.  It looks like you are just asking for $P(X=4)$, even though you insist you are not.  If you can, please explain how your question differs from $P(X=4)$.

Comment: I've tried, but I think I simply can't. Sorry.

Comment: Then I suggest you go with $P(X=4)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree to Graham Kemp that $\mathsf P(N=n)~=~\dfrac{n-1}{2^n}\mathbf 1_{n\in[2, ..., \infty)}$. But it asked for the probability that the number of total coins you flipped so far is $\underline{\textrm{equal}}$ to $4$. Therefore the required probability is

$$\mathsf P(N=4)~=~\dfrac{4-1}{2^4}=\frac3{16}$$

Answer (score 3):

Letting $N$ be the count of coins flipped until you obtain the second head.

You have that $\mathsf P(N=n)~=~\dfrac{n-1}{2^n}\mathbf 1_{n\in[[2..\infty)]}$

So, if you seek the probability the the number of coins you flip *until* the second head equals $4$, that is: $\mathsf P(N=4)$

However, if you seek to find $\mathsf P(N\geq 4)$, the number of coins flipped *so far* is 4 (ie that you have not stopped earlier)...$$\mathsf P(N\geq 4)~=~1-\mathsf P(N<4)\\=~~~~~$$

Comment: Wouldn't that be the probability of having flipped 4 or **more** coins? The question asks for it to be exactly 4.

Comment: @bedirhan What does "so far" mean to you?  To me it means "you may not have stopped yet."

Comment: Please check my replies to lulu's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of thinking about this is to just flip the coin exactly 4 times; we want the probability that the 4th of these 4 flips is the 2nd head. That is, the 4th flip should be heads and there should be exactly 1 head in the first 3 flips. There are 3 cases where this occurs, `HTTH`, `THTH`, and `TTHH` out of 16 possible sequences of four flips, so the answer is
$$\frac{3}{16}.$$